# Angular UI Router: 1 route working, the next not

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
$stateProvider
.state('state1', {
  url: "/state1",
  templateUrl: "partials/state1"
})
.state('state1.list', {
  url: "/list",
  templateUrl: "partials/state1list",
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
  }
})
```

The first route works and i see the `state1.jade` file rendered. But I don't see the `state1list.jade` file rendered using the same backend.

What is the `url:"/state1"` for, in angular-ui-router? If that's a possible issue.

I'm using nodejs, express so the server looks like

```
app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    console.log(name);
    res.render('partials/' + name);
});
```

Executing using [example at angular-ui@github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

```
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitted and [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/424) There is a typographical error:-
`var myApp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']);` should be `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);`

It is now committed, to the mainsite.

If you are implementing Multiple Views then you may want to take a look at ['template' should be 'templateUrl'](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/425) too.